# Convex hull has the smallest perimeter

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, convex-analysis

How do you show that the convex hull of a given set of points S, always has the minimum perimeter ? By perimeter i mean the length of the boundary of the hull

Comment: Minimum with respect to what? To all convex sets containing S? Cause if its w.r.t. all sets containing S, then it is not true. Take for instance the 4 corners of a square. obviously, the square is the convex hull, its boundary has length $4Z$, $Z$ being the length of one side. But the set of corner points itself has zero length.

Comment: I mean that the hull has the shortest perimeter of all simple polygons that include every point of S.

Answer (score 9):

Take an arbitrary simple polygon $\pi$ including every point of $S$, and take some segment $PQ$ of the convex hull. Extend it into a line $\ell$. Form a new polygon $\pi'$ by locating the "left"most and "right"most intersection points $L,R$ of $\ell$ with $\pi$, adding new vertices to $\pi$ at $L,R$, and replacing the part of $\pi$ between $L$ and $R$ by the single line segment $LR$. The resulting polygon $\pi'$ is a simple polygon including all points of $S$, and the triangle inequality implies that its perimeter is smaller or equal to the perimeter of $\pi$.

Comment: Wow I didn't think it was that easy... thank you Yuval !

Answer (score 0):

The steps for such demostration are indicated in the book of **Berg** "*Computational Geometry. Algorithms and aplications*".
**Exercise 1.1.**
The convex hull of a set S is defined to be the intersection of all convex
sets that contain S. For the convex hull of a set of points it was indicated that the convex hull is the convex set with smallest perimeter. We want to show that these are equivalent definitions.
**a.** Prove that the intersection of two convex sets is again convex. This implies that the intersection of a finite family of convex sets is convex as well.
**b.** Prove that the smallest perimeter polygon P containing a set of points P is convex.
**c.** Prove that any convex set containing the set of points P contains the smallest perimeter polygon P.