# Given a set of points $S$ in the plane $\mathbb{C}$, is there a way to define "the smallest Euclidean shape that $S$ makes"?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

For example, given $S := \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -1)\}$, I want to say, precisely, that the "smallest shape that $S$ makes" is something like the Star Trek symbol (https://1000logos.net/star-trek-logo/). I am thinking something like convex hull but obviously not convex. I'd like to define such a thing also for sets that are infinite. I've thought about "smallest" to mean "area", but I don't know enough analysis to intuit that this is a good idea.

If such a thing is definable, can I say that an uncountable, bounded, empty-interior set $S \subset \mathbb{C}$ is dense in this thing?

Comment: If your shape doesn't need to be convex, then there's no real notion of "smallest area" that works here. Consider the polygon with edges $(0, 0)\to (1, -1)$, $(1, -1)\to (\epsilon, 0)$, $(\epsilon, 0)\to (0, 1)$, $(0, 1)\to (-\epsilon, 0)$, $(-\epsilon, 0)\to (-1, -1)$, and $(-1, -1)\to (0, 0)$. This can have arbitrarily small area by letting $\epsilon$ get close to $0$.

Comment: On the other hand, the smallest *perimeter* shape that encloses a point set actually will be the [convex hull](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13148/convex-hull-has-the-smallest-perimeter).

Comment: You could try fixing a length $L$ and take the shape that gives the smallest area with perimeter $L$ that encloses the points.

Comment: Or if you look at the problem in [hyperbolic space](https://www.google.com/search?q=hyperbolic+triangle&source=lnms&tbm=isch) you might be able to a solution that looks something that looks like that symbol.